# how to access Google map on windows phone emulator?

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am working on a hybrid application which uses google map features , I have built the application using jquery mobile and phone gap, The application is working fine for android build.
When i build the same application for windows phone using cordova , Google map features are not accessible from windows phone emulator, Can i please know is their any specific setting needs to be enabled to access google map from windows phone or emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API should work on every platform without any special configurations. I'd check if the app can access an arbitary internet page. If this is not possible, you probably need to configure your app for internet access. See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection

Comment: my question was google.maps.com is not accessible from windows phone emulator , I went through article in the following link http://mashable.com/2013/01/05/google-maps-windows-phone/